# realloc'ed value not passed back to the calling function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, realloc

I'm writing a simple C program to understand C programming. Here's what my code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    void add(int** array, int size, int value)
     {
      if(!*array)
         *array = calloc(4,sizeof(int));
     if(size > 3)
     {
         *array = realloc(*array,6*sizeof(int));
     }
     *array[size] = value;  
 }

    int main()
    {
     int* numbers = NULL;
     int i;
     for(i=0; i<6; i++)
     {
         add(&numbers,i,i);
     }
     for(i=0; i<6; i++)
     {
         printf("%d\n",numbers[i]);
     }
     return 0;              
 }
```

What the function add should do is, put the given value at the given point of the array and if the array is not large enough, resize the array. Currently, what I'm getting is a segmentation fault. I tried GDB and it seems array variable does not get the value set by the add function. And I cannot understand why. Please help.

Comment: This has been asked so many times. Someone please find a duplicate.

Comment: You need to learn how to use GDB better; the variable is getting assigned just fine.  Besides, you aren't even calling `realloc` yet, since it crashes when `size`=1.

Comment: @2501 sorry if it's a duplicate. It's very hard to find an answer because of the very specific nature of my problem.

Comment: @Scott Hunter - I know, I'm just starting off with C pointers and GDB. Still confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you get the original pointer: `(*array)`, *then* you index it: `(*array)[i]`.

Operator `[]` has a higher precedence than the dereference `*` operator.

Comment: Thank you! I wasted an afternoon with this